# Is it possible to process two topics sequentially in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two topics `A` and `B` in a Kafka broker. Is it possible to consume those topics sequentially, instead of in parallel? Should I add those consumers to the same consumer group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have two sequential consumer loops, sure.

e.g

```
Duration d = Duration.ofMillis(100);
ConsumerRecords c1Records = consumer1.poll(d);
while (c1Records.hasNext()) {
  process1(c1Records.next());
}

ConsumerRecords c2Records = consumer2.poll(d);
while (c2Records.hasNext()) {
  process2(c2Records.next());
}
```

It doesn't matter if they are in the same consumer group because they are different topics. One group can consume multiple topics

Answer (score 0):

Since Kafka has polling mechanism, consumer behaviour can be controlled.
Following pseudo code can be build in Single thread.

- max.poll.records=1 //change as per specific use case
- Consumer1.poll(duration)
- Consumer2.poll(duration)

This will consume single message from each partition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process them sequentially, then you will need to do it in batches, as generally topics always are having records added to them.

To do this, when you start, take a snapshot of the start and end offsets of each topic. Then, as described earlier, poll the first topic until you read the target offset, then move on to polling the next topic until you reach the target offset. Then repeat.